# worker dont have sufficent memory

Tags: apache-spark

I get the following WARN-message:

```
TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
```

when i try to run the following spark-task:

```
spark/bin/spark-submit --master $SPARK_MASTER_URL --executor-memory 8g --driver-memory 8g --name "Test-Task" --class path.to.my.Class myJAR.jar
```

Master and all worker have enough memory for this task (see picture), but it seems like they don't get it allocated.

[image: status frontend]

My setup looks like this:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.executor.memory", "8g");
```

When I start my task and then type

```
ps -fux | more
```

in my console, it shows me these options:

```
-Xms512m -Xmx512m
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:
What I am doing:
I have a huge file saved on my master disk, which is about 5gb when I load it into memory (it's a map of maps). So I first load the whole map into memory and then give each node a part of this map to process. As I understand, that's the reason why I need much memory also on my master instance. Maybe not a good solution?

Comment: "in my console, it shows me these options: -Xms512m -Xmx512m" for which process?

Comment: `java -cp ::/home/spark/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.
4/conf:/home/spark/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-assembly-1.1.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar:/home/spark/spark-1.1.0-bi
n-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.1.jar:/home/spark/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.2.jar
:/home/spark/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.1.jar -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dspark.akka.logLi
fecycleEvents=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip spark-master-highmem --port 7077
 --webui-port 8080`

Comment: 512m  for the master is usually enough, as all it does is dispatching job to workers. Can you check the memory really available on worker nodes with "free -m" command or the like? Are there 11.7G available on each of them?

Comment: Yes, there are about 11g free on each node. But either I DO need more memory on my master or have to overthink my implementation: please have a look on my edit.

Comment: Alright. Do you launch your Master using start-master.sh or start-all.sh scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enlarge the heap size of the master node you can set `SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY` environment variable (in spark-env.sh for instance). But I doubt it will solve your memory allocation problem since the master node is not loading data.

I don't understand what your "map of maps" file is. But usually, to process a big file, you make it available to each worker node using a shared folder (NFS) or, better, a distributed file system (HDFS, GlusterFS). Then each worker can read a part of the file and process it. This works as long as the file format is splittable, Spark support [JSON file format](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets) for instance.